# What is the best way to get duration of a video using ffprobe (ffmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Most of the solutions to get duration revolves around parsing the output to get the duration. Even FFProbe official documentation [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Streamduration) says that there is no duration stored for MKV, webm, etc.

Take the below examples.

```
ffprobe -v error -i <inputmkv> -show_entries stream=...,duration,.. -of default=noprint_wrappers=1
```

This gives me the below output. This is not having duration.

[image: Image with Duration NA]

But when I run the same command differently like below, I am getting this output but having duration. Just removed '-v error' part.

```
ffprobe -i <inputmkv> -show_entries stream=...duration,... -of default=noprint_wrappers=1
```

[image]

If you notice the same command shows the duration in one place and not in another place.

So my question is, What is the best way to get duration in ffmpeg, especially for the video streams?

Edit: I have already explored decoding using null mux option. But that is a costly operation and also need to parse the output.

Comment: MKV file optionally has the DURATION stored in the Metadata (stored as MKV TAG).